# I need to duplicate a word file and name it based on an excel list or other list format

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, macros, vba

I have a base word file that I need to copy and name approximately 300 times.  The content of the word file will be the same, but the file name will be different based on a column within excel (or a list of any kind, doesn't matter)

I've combed through things a bit, and can't seem to find any direction on how to do something like this.  I would essentially like to batch copy the file, and then I could potentially use a file renaming utility, but I didn't know if there was a better way.  Potentially even scripted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this could work in a Windows command shell.

Create your list of desired filenames in a simple text file:

**FileNames.txt**, one filename per line.

```
filename1.docx  
filename2.docx 
filename3.docx 
...etc
```

Then run the following in a command window, assuming you replace **FileToCopy.docx** with your actual filename.

> C:\scripts>for /F %i IN (FileNames.txt) DO
>   copy FileToCopy.docx %i

Could obviously be refined greatly, but I think this would meet your requirements. What it will do is for every line in the FileNames.txt file, it will create a copy of FileToCopy.docx with that name.

Comment: Oh wow that totally worked.  Thanks man, is there a reference for that kind of thing that would be useful to a layman?

Comment: Not really sure... you could try the following?  http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true Probably not exactly 'layman friendly' though.. :|